# how to \emph a \csname?

Tags: etoolbox

How to `\emph` a `\csname\command\endcsname`??
I tried to use `\csgdef` and it works but not for `\csname` and I need to use `\csxdef`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,hidelinks]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{alphalph}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand \garotab {garota}
\newcommand \nveics {2}

\foreach \x [count=\xi from 2] in {b,...,\alphalph{\nveics}}{
% \csxdef{teste\x}{\emph{\csname garota\x\endcsname}}

\csxdef{rato\x}{\em ah garota}
\csgdef{gato\x}{\emph{ah garota}}
}

\begin{document}

{\testeb}\\

{\gatob}\\

{\ratob}\\

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\noexpand\emph`

Answer (score 2):

You need to avoid expanding `\emph`, so use `\noexpand` in front of it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{alphalph}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand \garotab {garota}
\newcommand \nveics {2}

\foreach \x [count=\xi from 2] in {b,...,\alphalph{\nveics}}{
  \csxdef{teste\x}{\noexpand\emph{\expandonce{\csname garota\x\endcsname}}}
  \csxdef{rato\x}{\noexpand\em ah garota}
  \csgdef{gato\x}{\emph{ah garota}}
}

\begin{document}

{\testeb}  

{\gatob}  

{\ratob}  

\end{document}
```

Note that in this way you have performed the same as

```
\def\testeb{\emph{\garotab}}
```

If you instead want to fully expand `\garotab` (which I'm not sure you do), change the line into

```
  \csxdef{teste\x}{\noexpand\emph{\csname garota\x\endcsname}}
```